# Error when using instruction map in angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jasmine, sonarqube

I started my angular project on sonar and for the test.ts sonar file I get an error for the following line:

```
context.keys().map(context);
```

Consider using "forEach" instead of "map" as its return value is not being used here

I don't understand why

Answer (score 4):

What `map` does is does transformation in its callback and returns the new transformed array as a new reference (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). The returned new transformed array is not being used and therefore Sonar is saying to change it to a `forEach`.

Changing it to `context.keys().forEach(context);` runs the unit tests for me and everything is fine however Angular CLI has it as `map` so I am going to keep it as `map`.

Comment: This instruction is in the test.ts file generated by angular when creating the application. Is it relevant to change it?

Comment: I personally would not change it.